# Background Image for Sprite-Kit Scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im working in a Sprite-Kit Scene right now and I want to set the Background to an image named "bgimage" for example. How would I do this programmatically through the gamescene.swift ?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import CoreGraphics
class gameScene: SKScene {


}
```

Comment: It is a good practice to use capitalised names for classes. Replacing `gameScene` with `GameScene` is advisable, through not necessary.

Answer (score 13):

You can declare your background image as an `SKSpriteNode`, set its position to the middle of the screen and add it to your scene.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class gameScene: SKScene {
    var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bgimage")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
        addChild(background)
    }
}
```

Also make sure you have the image in images.xcassets.

Comment: Setting its size to fill the scene would be great, too.

Comment: I think it will look better if you use device specific images for the background instead of universal. That way, every device has its own version of the image, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: @TheCodeComposer Great idea for iOS, but not OS X.

Comment: While this definitely does work, I have noticed that it can use up a lot of device resources, particularly on older devices.

Answer (score 4):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import CoreGraphics
class gameScene: SKScene {

var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bgimage")

override func didMoveToView(to view: SKView) {
background.zPosition = 1
background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)

addChild(background)


}
}
```

The zPosition should be lower than all the other Nodes in the gameScene

Comment: Swift 4 syntax change `override func didMove(to view: SKView) {` Also, thanks for the hint on the zPosition.

Answer (score 1):

Full-size image background

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    super.didMove(to:view)

    DispatchQueue.main.async{

        self.background.zPosition = 0
        self.background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
        self.background.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        self.addChild(self.background)

    }
}
```